# Runtime Library error in R with Random forest (Rborist)

Tags: r

I am using library `Rborist` in R,and one time I accomplished a task to construct a Random Forest model ,and to save the object with the function `saveRDS`.

Then, I shut down `R` , and loaded the object with the function `readRDS`.
It is when a error happened that I tried to predict using the Random Forest model.

This is the error message:

> Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
>
> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it an unusual
>   way. Please contact the application's support team for more
>   information.

This is the code:

```
library(caret) 
library(Rborist)

dat <- read.csv("data.csv", header=T)
dat <- transform(dat, y = as.factor(y))

index <- createDataPartition(dat$y, p=.8, list=F)
train <- dat[index, ];test  <- dat[-index,]
model <- Rborist(train[,-1], train$y, predProb=0.1, nTree = 500)

table = table(predict(model, test[,-1])$yPred,test$y)

table
sum(diag(table))/sum(table)
saveRDS(model,file="model.rds")

#once shut down ,and boot up R
library(Rborist)
test <- read.csv("test.csv", header=T)
model <- readRDS(file="model.rds")
pred = predict(model, test[,-1])$yPred # Error!!
```

Comment: I would suggest to file a bug report on the package's GitHub

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I tried iris data set and, the result is the same. I am going to  do as you say.